# How do I create a Fedora 16 live usb from Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb, fedora, live-environment

UNetBootin and LiveUSB Install don't support Fedora 16 yet, so how do I manually create a live USB?

Comment: This question is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. It is actually a question about Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB

Comment: `sudo dd if=/Users/me/Downloads/Fedora-17-x86_64-DVD.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M`

Comment: Giving link to a page which has lengthy complected answer doesn't fit as the answer.